# Removing a node from binary tree

Tags: python, binary-tree

I'm currently working on leetcode problem 366 where we have to find list of lists that contains values of leaves of each generation. I wanted to achieve this by recursion where if a node does not have left or right child, the value is recorded then the node removed by setting it to None. Here is my code:

```
def findLeaves(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> List[List[int]]:
    leaf_list = []
    sub_list = []
    def traverse(node):
        if node == None:
            return
        if node.left == None and node.right == None:
            sub_list.append(node.val)
            node = None
            return 
        traverse(node.left)
        traverse(node.right)
        return root
    
    while True:
        if root == None:
            break
        sub_list = []
        traverse(root)
        leaf_list.append(sub_list)
        print(leaf_list)
    return leaf_list
```

The problem seems to be that when a certain node is set to None, that change isn't retained. Why is it that I can't set a node to None to remove it?

Thanks

Comment: There is a difference between changing `node` and changing the part of the tree that points to `node`.

Comment: could you please elaborate on that? If at 3rd recursion node is root.left.left.left and that node is an instance of class TreeNode, wouldn't setting node = None equate removing root.left.left.left?

Comment: Obviously not, or you wouldn't be here.   If you want root.left.left.left to be None, you have to assign None to *that*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tree can only be mutated when you assign to one if its node's attributes. An assignment to a *variable*, only changes what the variable represents. Such assignment *never* impacts whatever *previous* value that variable had. Assigning to a variable is like switching from one value to another without affecting any data structure. So you need to adapt your code such that the assignment of `None` is done to a `left` or `right` attribute.

The exception is for the root node itself. When the root is a leaf, then there is no parent to mutate. You will then just discard the tree and switch to an empty one (`None`).

One way to achieve this, is to use the *return* value of `traverse` to update the child-reference (`left` or `right`) that the caller of `traverse` needs to update.

Here is your code with those adaptations:

```
def findLeaves(root):
    sub_list = []
    def traverse(node):
        if not node:
            return
        if not node.left and not node.right:
            sub_list.append(node.val)
            return  # By returning None, the parent can remove it
        node.left = traverse(node.left)  # Assign the returned node reference
        node.right = traverse(node.right)
        return node  # Return the node (parent does not need to remove it)
    
    leaf_list = []
    while root:
        sub_list = []
        root = traverse(root)
        leaf_list.append(sub_list)
    return leaf_list
```